# An integer is returned modified, but my getter function doesn't modify it. Any ideas?

Tags: java, setter, getter

I have two classes, one is called CreateDefault, which creates GUI setting for my program. My other class is tabPanePopup, which creates a popup and its commands for my JTabbedPane associated with CreateDefault.

```
public int getCount() { return this.count; }
```

The code above, returns count. Count, counts how many New documents have been created. getCount() is part of the CreateDefault class.

The below code is part of the tabPanePopup. The action newTab performs is already written out. In CreateDefault, count = 1, originally, then it is increased by 1 when the GUI is completely created, totaling count = 2. When getCount() is called in the tabPanePopup class, getCount() should return 2, but it returns 1. If I do a println function on count in the CreateDefault class, it prints 2, but it prints 1 in tabPanePopup. Is there any reason it is doing this? I don't modify count at all other then count++ when the GUI is created, and the getCount() function cannot be called until after the GUI is created.

```
newTab.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
            CreateDefault get = new CreateDefault();
            int count = get.getCount();
            String parsed = Integer.toString(count);
            Font myFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 12);
            JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane,
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            LineCounter counter = new LineCounter(editorPane);
            UndoManager manager = new UndoManager();
            Document document = editorPane.getDocument();
            document.addUndoableEditListener(manager);
            scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(counter);
            counter.setBackground(Color.white);
            tabPane.setFont(myFont);
            tabPane.addTab("New Document " + parsed, scrollPane);
            tabPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
            get.setCount(count++);
        }   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess since there is much to your code that has yet to be revealed to us, but it appears that you're creating a new CreateDefault object in the method above, and it is likely to be completely unrelated to the CreateDefault instance that is holding the *true* count result. The key is not to create a new object and call `getCount()` on it, but to call this method on the *original* instance. The solution is to somehow get a reference to this original instance.

So instead of:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
  CreateDefault get = new CreateDefault();
  int count = get.getCount();
```

Do something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
  // CreateDefault get = new CreateDefault();
  int count = createDefault.getCount();
```

where the createDefault variable somehow references the original CreateDefault instance.

Comment: I see, thank-you. But doing this creates a static variable, which I've had a tendency to use them needlessly. I'm trying to avoid them. Is there a way different method I can use to access getCount() in a non static way?

Comment: @StevenTylerFrizell: No, I never said to use a static variable, and in fact strongly urge you *not* to do this. Create and use an instance field. You may need to give the class where this code is located a `setCreateDefault(CreateDefault createDefault)` method so you can pass in the reference.

Comment: Okay, so setCreateDefault(CreateDefualt createDefualt) must go in my tabPanePopup class? If so, I did that, and called setCreateDefault function in my CreateDefault class and sent tabPanePopup the current instance of CreateDefault. Am I following correctly?

Comment: @StevenTyler: I guess... there's a *lot* about your program that I am not familiar with, so I can only help so far. It's all limited by what you tell us.

Comment: Well, now I recieve a NullPointerException error when int count = createDefault.getCount() is called. Crap. I'll have to fiddle with it more, but thank-you for helping. I got the brief idea of what I need to do.

Comment: You must make sure to *call* the setCreateDefault method, and that you are passing in a viable non-null reference when you call it.